# conexão reversa em C#

Tags: c#, conexão, dns, tcpclient

Estou tendo dificuldade em usar conexão reversa entre cliente e servidor.
Sempre que eu tento realizar conectar usando Dns ou Ip não conecta, caso eu uso o LocalHost, 127.0.0.1, ele conecta perfeitamente.
Ele ja consegue "resolver" o IP do DNS
Oque preciso fazer para que seja possível conetar ?

```
private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);



        public static TcpClient client;
        private const int _PORT = 28562; //  porta


         public static string connectTo = "decodertm.ddns.net";// Não conecta
        // public static string connectTo = "127.0.0.1";// conecta

        public static IPAddress ipaddress = null;
```

.

```
 private static void ConnectToServer()
        {

            int attempts = 0;


            bool IsValidIP = IPAddress.TryParse(connectTo, out ipaddress);

            if (IsValidIP == false)
            {

                ipaddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(connectTo)[0];
                //   Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostAddresses(connectTo)[0]);


            }  
            client = new TcpClient();


            while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
            {                 
                try 
                {                     
                    attempts++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Tentativas de conectar " + attempts); 
               _clientSocket.Connect("177.201.126.8", _PORT);         
                    Thread.Sleep(100);  

                }
                catch (SocketException)  
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Conectado !");

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Se em localhost conecta perfeitamente e no dns dinamico não conecta (provavelmente ele está configurado con seu IP), isto é por causa da sua rede!

**Se o IP do DDNS for o seu:**

Você deve configurar sua rede corretamente, ela deve estar em modo NAT para haver uma conexão. Se não estiver em modo NAT, não vai se conectar!

Não te ensino a fazer isso, pois os roteadores, modens e mais, são diferentes as configurações, olhe o modelo do mesmo e dê uma pesquisada sobre NAT!

**Se você está tentando se conectar direto no host:**

Tente usar:

```
var ips = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("microsoft.com").AddressList;
foreach (var ip in ips)
    Console.WriteLine(ip);
```

Vai retornar um ip ou mais para você para você!

.

Não sei se conseguir te ajudar, mas, espero que sim!